# jquery method only calls webmethod the 1st time and bypasses any other time it's called

Tags: c#, jquery, json, jstree, webmethod

I have a webmethod that returns a json string and populates a jstree and all works perfectly the 1st click of a text box.  Each time a user clicks a different text box, it passes different values in the jquery but the webmethod actually doesn't get called after the 1st time it's called.  So I'm wondering what I need to clear in order for it do call the webmethod each time.

```
function showtree1(thisID, line) {
    $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree.empty;
    $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({
        "core": {

            "data": //data - jquery
              {
                  type: "POST"
                  , dataType: "json"
                  , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

                  , url: "FlowCycleReport.aspx/populateTree"

                  //, data: "{'imgID':'" + thisID + "'}"
                  , data: JSON.stringify({ imgID: thisID, line: line })
                  //, "data": function (node) {
                  //    //return "{'id':'" + $(node).attr("id") + "'}";
                  //    return node.d;

                  //}
                  , success: function (node) {
                      var ReturnString = node.d;
                     // alert(ReturnString);
                      return { "id": node.id };
                  }///success


                  , error: function (msg) {

                      alert("Error: " + msg.responseText);

                  }///error
              }//data
        }///core
,
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "search", "contextmenu", "types"]

    });
}
```

WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
    //public static string populateTree(string imgID, int node)
    public static string populateTree(string imgID, string line)
    {
        DAL_Flow DL = new DAL_Flow();
        //string line = "278";

        string nodevalues = DL.JsonNav(imgID, line);

        return nodevalues;

    }
```

onclick event:

```
$(function () {
        $(".textbox").click(function (e) {

            var thisID = $(e.target).attr("ID");

            var csID = thisID.substr(thisID.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
            $('#posDetailDiv').hide();


            var line = $('#dlLine').val();

            // Reset the header:
            $('#PartHeaderDiv').empty();
            $('#PartHeaderDiv').append('Line Number: ' + line + ': Control Station ' + csID);

            showtree1(csID, line);

            $('#posDetailDiv').show();


        });
    });
```

script manager:

```
   <asp:toolkitscriptmanager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" ></asp:toolkitscriptmanager>
```

The values for CSID and line changes on my header each click but the treeview values don't.

I've put a breakpoint on the webmethod to verify that the webmethod isn't getting hit.

I'm sure I'm just missing something.

Can anyone help?

Comment: why do you completely wipe out the tree each time a user input is clicked? the plugin has a robust API for managing data.

Comment: I need to refresh the tree each time b/c I am passing different parameters to populate the tree.  Lazy loading doesn't work with the browswer we are using which is why I load it each time.  I've actually got the refresh piece working with $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree("refresh"); so that's aweome.  But now, when it's hitting my webmethod the 2nd time, although the params from the jquery are correct, the webmethod still has the 1st params that were passed.

Comment: non of that makes any sense when the plugin can do it all for you, params or no params

Comment: Do yo u have an example?

Answer (score 1):

First thing i can think of is that since you wipe out everything and rebuild it every time it is clicked, your `.click` event gets wiped out too since it is not dynamically bonded. So instead of doing:

```
$(".textbox").click(function (e) {
```

you can do:

```
$(".textbox").on('click', function (e) {
    //click event code goes here
});
```

so your click event would be registered all the time even for the dynamic `.textbox` elements that are added later on.